# How do I build a rank function that ranks ascending or descending based on defined column names?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm looking to build a function that ranks the variables either in ascending or descending fashion based on the name of the variable defined within the function.

I am able to do the ranks manually, but I want to be able to call on the function in order to streamline the code for my `df`.  Looking for someone to show me how to do the function on a wide, and long `df`.  My sample code is below.  I'm looking to have tov, and minutes ranked ascending, with the other columns all ranked in descending order.  It would be great if someone could show me how to do the function so that I define the variable names for both the ascending and descending ranked variables, and another option where I only define the variables to be ranked descending, with all other columns defaulting to ascending ranks.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
                ~Name, ~Team, ~minutes, ~ftm, ~fta, ~oreb, ~dreb, ~treb, ~ast, ~stl, ~blk, ~tov, ~pts, ~eff,
  "Russell Westbrook", "OKC",     34.6,  8.8, 10.4,   1.7,     9,  10.7, 10.4,  1.6,  0.4,  5.4, 31.6, 33.8,
       "James Harden", "HOU",     36.4,  9.2, 10.9,   1.2,     7,   8.1, 11.2,  1.5,  0.5,  5.7, 29.1, 32.4,
      "Isaiah Thomas", "BOS",     33.8,  7.8,  8.5,   0.6,   2.1,   2.7,  5.9,  0.9,  0.2,  2.8, 28.9, 24.7,
      "Anthony Davis", "NOP",     36.1,  6.9,  8.6,   2.3,   9.5,  11.8,  2.1,  1.3,  2.2,  2.4,   28, 31.1,
      "DeMar DeRozan", "TOR",     35.4,  7.4,  8.7,   0.9,   4.3,   5.2,  3.9,  1.1,  0.2,  2.4, 27.3, 22.7,
     "Damian Lillard", "POR",     35.9,  6.5,  7.3,   0.6,   4.3,   4.9,  5.9,  0.9,  0.3,  2.6,   27, 24.5,
   "DeMarcus Cousins", "NOP",     34.2,  7.2,  9.3,   2.1,   8.9,    11,  4.6,  1.4,  1.3,  3.7,   27, 28.5,
       "LeBron James", "CLE",     37.8,  4.8,  7.2,   1.3,   7.3,   8.6,  8.7,  1.2,  0.6,  4.1, 26.4,   31,
      "Kawhi Leonard", "SAS",     33.4,  6.3,  7.2,   1.1,   4.7,   5.8,  3.5,  1.8,  0.7,  2.1, 25.5, 25.3,
      "Stephen Curry", "GSW",     33.4,  4.1,  4.6,   0.8,   3.7,   4.5,  6.6,  1.8,  0.2,    3, 25.3, 25.2
  )

df_wide <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ftm, ast), funs(rank = rank(desc(.)))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(tov, minutes), funs(rank = rank((.))))

df_wide
#> # A tibble: 10 x 18
#>    Name  Team  minutes   ftm   fta  oreb  dreb  treb   ast   stl   blk
#>    <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Russ~ OKC      34.6   8.8  10.4   1.7   9    10.7  10.4   1.6   0.4
#>  2 Jame~ HOU      36.4   9.2  10.9   1.2   7     8.1  11.2   1.5   0.5
#>  3 Isai~ BOS      33.8   7.8   8.5   0.6   2.1   2.7   5.9   0.9   0.2
#>  4 Anth~ NOP      36.1   6.9   8.6   2.3   9.5  11.8   2.1   1.3   2.2
#>  5 DeMa~ TOR      35.4   7.4   8.7   0.9   4.3   5.2   3.9   1.1   0.2
#>  6 Dami~ POR      35.9   6.5   7.3   0.6   4.3   4.9   5.9   0.9   0.3
#>  7 DeMa~ NOP      34.2   7.2   9.3   2.1   8.9  11     4.6   1.4   1.3
#>  8 LeBr~ CLE      37.8   4.8   7.2   1.3   7.3   8.6   8.7   1.2   0.6
#>  9 Kawh~ SAS      33.4   6.3   7.2   1.1   4.7   5.8   3.5   1.8   0.7
#> 10 Step~ GSW      33.4   4.1   4.6   0.8   3.7   4.5   6.6   1.8   0.2
#> # ... with 7 more variables: tov <dbl>, pts <dbl>, eff <dbl>,
#> #   ftm_rank <dbl>, ast_rank <dbl>, tov_rank <dbl>, minutes_rank <dbl>

df_long <- df %>%
  gather(key = data_col, value = "stat_value", 3:14) %>% 
  group_by(data_col) %>% 
  mutate(rank = if_else(data_col %in% c("tov", "minutes"), rank(stat_value, ties.method = "first"), rank(-stat_value, ties.method = "first")))

df_long
#> # A tibble: 120 x 5
#> # Groups:   data_col [12]
#>    Name              Team  data_col stat_value  rank
#>    <chr>             <chr> <chr>         <dbl> <int>
#>  1 Russell Westbrook OKC   minutes        34.6     5
#>  2 James Harden      HOU   minutes        36.4     9
#>  3 Isaiah Thomas     BOS   minutes        33.8     3
#>  4 Anthony Davis     NOP   minutes        36.1     8
#>  5 DeMar DeRozan     TOR   minutes        35.4     6
#>  6 Damian Lillard    POR   minutes        35.9     7
#>  7 DeMarcus Cousins  NOP   minutes        34.2     4
#>  8 LeBron James      CLE   minutes        37.8    10
#>  9 Kawhi Leonard     SAS   minutes        33.4     1
#> 10 Stephen Curry     GSW   minutes        33.4     2
#> # ... with 110 more rows
```

My desired output would be the same as the `df` listed above.  I'm looking to create a function that cleans up the manual if_else, and 2 lines of code above.  Let's say the function was called `stat_rank`.  I'd want the code to operate something like:

```
df_wide <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ftm, ast, tov, minutes), funs(rank = stat_rank(.)))) 


df_long <- df %>%
  gather(key = data_col, value = "stat_value", 3:14) %>% 
  group_by(data_col) %>% 
  mutate(rank = stat_rank(stat_value))
```

Comment: What is your expected output `am able to do the ranks manually, but I want to be able to call on the function in order to streamline the code for my df`. You showed two code snippets.  Tell us the issue in the code

Comment: I just edited my question above to show sample outcome, with how I envision the function working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a single function, then

```
stat_rank <- function(x) {
     col1 <- deparse(substitute(x))
     if(col1 %in% c('ftm', 'ast')) {
     rank(desc(x)) 
     } else rank(x)

}

df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(ftm, ast, tov, minutes), funs(rank = stat_rank))
# A tibble: 10 x 18
#   Name         Team  minutes   ftm   fta  oreb  dreb  treb   ast   stl   blk   tov   pts   eff ftm_rank ast_rank tov_rank minutes_rank
#   <chr>        <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 Russell Wes… OKC      34.6   8.8  10.4   1.7   9    10.7  10.4   1.6   0.4   5.4  31.6  33.8        2      2        9            5  
# 2 James Harden HOU      36.4   9.2  10.9   1.2   7     8.1  11.2   1.5   0.5   5.7  29.1  32.4        1      1       10            9  
# 3 Isaiah Thom… BOS      33.8   7.8   8.5   0.6   2.1   2.7   5.9   0.9   0.2   2.8  28.9  24.7        3      5.5      5            3  
# 4 Anthony Dav… NOP      36.1   6.9   8.6   2.3   9.5  11.8   2.1   1.3   2.2   2.4  28    31.1        6     10        2.5          8  
# 5 DeMar DeRoz… TOR      35.4   7.4   8.7   0.9   4.3   5.2   3.9   1.1   0.2   2.4  27.3  22.7        4      8        2.5          6  
# 6 Damian Lill… POR      35.9   6.5   7.3   0.6   4.3   4.9   5.9   0.9   0.3   2.6  27    24.5        7      5.5      4            7  
# 7 DeMarcus Co… NOP      34.2   7.2   9.3   2.1   8.9  11     4.6   1.4   1.3   3.7  27    28.5        5      7        7            4  
# 8 LeBron James CLE      37.8   4.8   7.2   1.3   7.3   8.6   8.7   1.2   0.6   4.1  26.4  31          9      3        8           10  
# 9 Kawhi Leona… SAS      33.4   6.3   7.2   1.1   4.7   5.8   3.5   1.8   0.7   2.1  25.5  25.3        8      9        1            1.5
#10 Stephen Cur… GSW      33.4   4.1   4.6   0.8   3.7   4.5   6.6   1.8   0.2   3    25.3  25.2       10      4        6            1.5
```

---

Note that in the above implementaion, the column names are hard-coded within the function.  If need to be more flexible, then can pass column names as another argument

```
stat_rank <- function(x, descCols) {
     col1 <- deparse(substitute(x))
     if(col1 %in% descCols) {
     rank(desc(x)) 
     } else rank(x)

}

df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(ftm, ast, tov, minutes), 
           funs(rank = stat_rank(., descCols = c('ftm', 'ast'))))
```

For the long format data, a function can be

```
stat_rankL = function(x, y, descCols) {
     ifelse(x %in% descCols, rank(desc(y)), rank(y))

}  
df %>%
   gather(key = data_col, value = "stat_value", 3:14) %>% 
   group_by(data_col) %>% 
   mutate(rank = stat_rankL(data_col, stat_value, c('ftm', 'ast')))
```